# date library, capable of calculating things like "every third tuesday"?

Tags: python, date

I'd like to find a library or command that given input like "every third tuesday" will provide a list of dates such as (2010-06-15, 2010-07-20, 2010-08-17), etc.

Something that can be called from python, unix command line, or a web api would be perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's always [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).
Example below is based on [~unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu)'s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295765/generating-recurring-dates-using-python/2296384#2296384) to [this very similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295765/generating-recurring-dates-using-python):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from dateutil import rrule, relativedelta
>>> every_third_tuesday = rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, 
                                      byweekday=relativedelta.TU(3), 
                                      dtstart=date.today(), 
                                      count=3)
>>> for tt in every_third_tuesday:
...   print tt.date()
... 
2010-07-20
2010-08-17
2010-09-21
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `calendar` module.  Here is a good writeup -- it is part of what you are asking for: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/calendar/index.html